# How to bulk rename JSON files?

Tags: python

I am trying to rename and replace a certain text with the hexadecimal for thousands of JSON files.

Could you help how to rename and replace them in bulk files?

For instance, the current file name is 10 and it has 10 in the JSON file, I
would like to rename/switch to A.

[image]

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/python-rename-file.html

Comment: Simply convert the file counter or index to hexadecimal before using it at the file name. There are several ways to do that, but since you've posted no code, it's hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a theoretical solution:

```py
import os

file_names = ["1_file.json", "10_file.json", "27_file.json", "44_file.json"]

for file in file_names:
   file_name_parts = file.split('_')
   file_name_parts[0] = hex(int(file_name_parts[0])).replace('0x', '').upper()
   renamed_file = '_'.join(file_name_parts)
   print(file, 'will be',  renamed_file)
   os.rename(file, renamed_file)
```

```
1_file.json will be 1_file.json
10_file.json will be A_file.json
27_file.json will be 1B_file.json
44_file.json will be 2C_file.json
```

Other stuff depends on details that you didn't describe